# How to put $f(x)=\begin{cases}1, &|x| \le 1,\\ 0, &|x|>1. \end{cases}$ into content?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, texstudio, cases

```latex
\documentclass[18pt,a4paper]{article}

...


\tableofcontents

...

\subsection{$f(x)=\begin{cases}1, &|x| \le 1,\\ 0, &|x|>1. \end{cases}$}
```

I compile it, TeXstudio gives me an error:

> "Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{cases}$ }"

How to put the formula into content?

Comment: Do you _really_ want to use a relatively big formula as section header?

Comment: Don't do this. Rather give names to your cases.

Comment: thank everyone ,I won't do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{$f(x) = \protect\begin{cases} 2 & \vert x \vert < 3 \\ -5 & \vert x \vert > 4 \protect\end{cases}$}

\subsection{$f(x) = \protect\begin{cases} 1 & \vert x \vert < 1 \\ 0 & \vert x \vert > 1 \protect\end{cases}$}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better `\lvert...\rvert` than `\vert...\vert`.